# Where does field help text get filtered?

Tags: entities, security

Drupal 7 fields, by default, have a nice text box beneath them for Help Text.  This is set up with [`field_ui_field_edit_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field_ui%21field_ui.admin.inc/function/field_ui_field_edit_form/7):

```
$form['instance']['description'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Help text'),
  '#default_value' => !empty($instance['description']) ? $instance['description'] : '',
  '#rows' => 5,
  '#description' => t('Instructions to present to the user below this field on the editing form.<br />Allowed HTML tags: @tags', array('@tags' => _field_filter_xss_display_allowed_tags())),
'#weight' => -5,
);
```

Widget forms then can use this when they actually get used, such as from [`file_field_widget_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.field.inc/function/file_field_widget_form/7):

```
if (empty($element['#default_value']['fid'])) {
  $element['#description'] = theme('file_upload_help', array('description' => $element['#description'], 'upload_validators' => $element['#upload_validators']));
}
```

Which then get themed, such as with [`theme_file_upload_help()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.field.inc/function/theme_file_upload_help/7)

```
if (strlen($description)) {
  $descriptions[] = $description;
}
if (isset($upload_validators['file_validate_size'])) {
  $descriptions[] = t('Files must be less than !size.', array('!size' => '<strong>' . format_size($upload_validators['file_validate_size'][0]) . '</strong>'));
}
if (isset($upload_validators['file_validate_extensions'])) {
  $descriptions[] = t('Allowed file types: !extensions.', array('!extensions' => '<strong>' . check_plain($upload_validators['file_validate_extensions'][0]) . '</strong>'));
}
```

The trusty eye will notice that this is user supplied text and it is not being filtered (oh noes!).  Don't worry, it gets filtered somewhere (I actually tested this to be sure).

Where / how does this filtering happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `function field_default_form` in *field.form.inc*
line 107

```
'#description' => field_filter_xss($instance['description']),
```

Comment: +1 also check out `field_multiple_value_form()` which might be used instead depending on the field's multi-value settings.